# How to multiply and reduce_max efficiently in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have 2 variables A and B with shapes (N,M) and (M,K).
I can calculate `C = tf.matmul(A, B)` and get new matrix C with shape (N, K).
Or I can rewrite this as `C = tf.reduce_sum(tf.expand_dims(A, -1) * tf.expand_dims(B, 0), 1)`. Obviously, that expression is slower and requires much more memory to calculate.

I'd like to calculate `C = tf.reduce_max(tf.expand_dims(A, -1) * tf.expand_dims(B, 0), 1)`. Kinda multiply two matrices, but set new element C<sub>i,j</sub> = max<sub>k</sub>(A<sub>i,k</sub>*B<sub>k,j</sub>). Is there any optimized form of this similar to `tf.matmul`?

Comment: I think the approach you are using is the best you can get (unless you implement your own op or something like that). If you have problems with memory you could use a loop, although that would probably be slower.

Comment: @rx303: Can you please let us know if your issue is resolved now. Thanks!

Comment: @TensorflowSupport yes, I've found a workaround

Comment: @rx303: Thank you for the response. Can you please mention the Solution either in the Comments Section or in the Answer Section, as it would help the Community.

Comment: @TensorflowSupport Sorry, but that was too long ago, so I don't remember it. Quite possible that I just reformulated original task so that I didn't had to make computation in question.